# Find the area of ​the triangular region ABC

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference;Calculate the area of ​​the triangular region ABC,
if : $CK = a$ ($T$ is tangency point)9Answer:$a^2$}

My progress:
[image]

I'm in difficulties .. I don't see many alternatives
$S_{ABC} = \frac{AB.BC}{2}\\
S_{ABC} = r(\frac{AB+BC+AC}{2}\\
s_{ABC} = AT.TC\\
TS^2+(2r)^2 = (2R)^2\implies TS=\sqrt{4R^2-4r^2}=2\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\\
$

...???

Comment: You write answer as $r^2$, it should be $a^2$.

Comment: @MyMolecules thanks for alert...I've already corrected

Comment: $CK^2=CS\cdot CT$.

Comment: What/why is your $s_{ABC} = AT \cdot TC$? If $s$ is the semiperimeter, I'd say instead $s = AT+TC+r$.

Comment: @aschepler (property) : The area of ​​a right triangle is equal to the product of the lengths of the segments determined by the circumference inscribed on the hypotenuse "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the usual notation, the incircle touches the sides of a triangle at $s-a,s-b,s-c$ from the vertices $A,B,C$ respectively.

$B$-excircle touches $AC$ at $(s-c)$ from $A$ and $(s-a)$ from $C$. So if $D$ were to be tangency point of $B$-excircle, then $CD=AF$ and $CF=AD$.

[image]

$B$-excircle is just a magnified version of incircle (or the two circles are homothetic wrt $B$). Every point on its circumference is collinear with corresponding point on the incircle and the vertex $B$. In particular, its tangency point on $AC$, which is its uppermost point, is in line with the uppermost point of incircle and $B$. From the collinearity of $B,E,D$, it turns out that $D$ is indeed the touch-point of the excircle.

Set $s-a=x$ and $s-c=y$. Lets observe :

- $CK^2=CD \times CF=xy$
- $x-y=(s-a)-(s-c)=c-a$

Now we are ready for the solution.
$$(x+y)^2=(x-y)^2+4xy $$ $$\Rightarrow b^2 = (a-c)^2+4CK^2$$
$$\Rightarrow b^2=a^2+c^2-2ac+4CK^2$$
Since $b^2=a^2+c^2$ and $S_{ABC}=ac/2$, it follows that
$$0=-4S_{ABC}+4CK^2$$
$$\therefore \boxed{S_{ABC}=CK^2}$$

Comment: As the OP already knows the formula $area=AF\cdot CF$, once you have proven $CD=AF$ and $CK^2=CD\cdot CF$ you're done.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Indeed. But just for sake of completeness and simplicity...